Dual UK Australian national visiting Vietnam
I have dual Australian and UK citizenship/passports. I am leaving Australia, travelling to Vietnam, then returning to Australia after 13 days.
I was planning to leave Australia with my Australian passport, enter and leave Vietnam with my UK passport, and then enter Australia with my Australian passport.
To complicate things, I have booked flights under my Australian passport, and according to the travel company we booked it under, changing the passport will incur a fee.
I'd rather not have to pay the fee (as it would make trying to travel visa-free null and void) so I was wondering if my previous entry/exit plan will work?
Or will I need a visa in the end? Thank you

@NicolasFormichella Because UK citizens don't need a Viet visa, but Australiams do.

I did exactly the same as your plan last year, and it was fine.  Showed EU nationality at check-in (to prove I can enter Vietnam visa-free), Australian passport on leaving Australia, EU passport on arrival at VN immigration, all good.  On the way back, Australian passport at check-in, EU passport at VN exit immigration, Australian passport in Australia.
This assumes your names are identical on both passports and match the ticket, otherwise things can get more complicated.

Pay a fee to change the passport? Yet another reason not to use an OTA...
Have you tried managing your booking directly on the airline's website and changing it there? While many changes are often blocked on the airline's website for TA-booked trips, some like passports (and even seat allocations, sometimes) can possibly still be changed.
But it the worst case, you just give the right passport at check-in and/or boarding and they will use that info.
Note that for your trip back you will need to switch back to your AU passport, or they will complain you don't have an ETA/eVisitor matching your UK passport.
Remember that the passport you show the airline is in the majority of cases just for the destination country (to see if you fulfil the conditions of entry). You can present a different passport to the airline and to the exit passport control at the airport of departure.

This assumes your details (name, dob...) are the same on both passports.

changing the passport will incur a fee

Any information you give online to the airline (like passport number...) can easily be overridden by check-in/gate agent for free (source), you just need to present yourself at check in.

Given your situation, using both passports should work, but it might complicate things slightly. Since your flights are booked under your Australian passport, you can:
Leave and enter Australia with your Australian passport.
Enter and leave Vietnam with your UK passport.
Just make sure to carry both passports and be prepared to show them if asked. This way, you can take advantage of visa-free travel in Vietnam with your UK passport. However, double-check Vietnam's entry requirements for UK citizens to ensure there are no issues. Safe travels!

This is a poor copy of the other answers, which makes it useless for OP. Please only post answers you know are right and when pointed out you are wrong see if you can improve your given answer.
